# Does Windbg's "!chkimg" report false-positives on W10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, driver, windbg, wdk

I am developing a very complicated driver on latest Windows 10-x64 (embedded/IoT distribution). Since I have some crashes (my fault), I tried to use !chkimg command to investigate memory corruptions. I discovered that the command always reports lot of errors in NT module, mainly in memory manager's functions. It is neither due to my driver nor to some weird thirdy-party's one, as it happens also on a fresh installation. Here some output line:

```
0: kd> !chkimg -d -lo 50
    fffff803bca1a594-fffff803bca1a595  2 bytes - nt!MiDuplicateCloneLeaf+38
    [ 80 fa:00 c1 ]
    fffff803bca1b24f-fffff803bca1b250  2 bytes - nt!MiExpandPagedPool+83 (+0xcbb)
    [ 80 f6:00 af ]
(...enough, enough!)
```

I checked the affected code (ok, some points), and observer that most of the errors are very similar. Example:

```
 nt!MiDuplicateCloneLeaf:
...
fffff803`bca1a58e 48b90000000000c1ffff mov rcx,0FFFFC10000000000h
```

The "original" code would be:

```
nt!MiDuplicateCloneLeaf:
...
fffff803`bca1a58e 48b90000000080faffff mov rcx,0FFFFFA8000000000h
```

My guess is that what I observed is an effect of some randomization of paging root's view in kernel (in particular PML4 self-reference entry position). Am I right? Is this a well-known issue, or is there something very weird in my machine?

In short, can someone explan what is going on?

Comment: does it happen on all systems? maybe the file is damaged on the HDD. run chkdsk and sfc or DISM to look if all Windows files are fine

Comment: Verified on two different systems.

Comment: There are more than 50 points, all belonging to memory manager and affecting similar instruction in similar ways. I would exclude that they are due to random corruptions. By the way, the system works perfectly.

Comment: Yes/No questions are not very suitable for SO. Peraps you can rephrase and ask why this is happening

Comment: My answer was deleted, but, yes, this is a known issue with the tools. You just need to filter out this noise and look elsewhere for the root cause

Comment: in the latest windbg (Creators update sdk), I see **Memory manager detected 1 instance(s) of corrupted pagefilepage(s) while performing in-page operations.** for a crash that I had today. so tomorrow I'Ll check the disk. also try latest windbg from insider sdk what windbg tells you

Comment: @snoone ok, so the answer is "yes, it's a known issue, your system doesn't have any particular problem". I'll accept the answer if you post it again. By the way, is this problem somewhat related to kernel paging randomization?

Comment: have you tried the latest insider SDK? does it detect what is wrong?

Comment: @magicandre1981: clarification: I don't have any real code corruption, only false positives reported by !chkimg. They don't depend on my code, in fact they appear even if I don't load my driver (and, by the way, I resolved my crashes these days). What puzzles me is the noisy output that makes the tool almost unusable.

Comment: I never saw this until this actual crash 2 days ago. Which windows 10 build + Windbg build do you use? use the Windbg build for the matching win10 builds

Comment: "Yes, known issue your system doesn't have any particular problem." And, yes, I believe it's due to the new dynamic relocation